# Tensorflow multiplication of constants performance slower than tf.random

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, tensor

I'm using Tensorflow for some non-DL computation, and I'm running into a behaviour I don't understand. I am testing the multiplication of a square matrix by itself: `tf.matmul(a,a)`:

1. when the matrix is created with tf.constant
2. when the matrix is randomly initialized at each run

My expectation is that the first case should have some overhead for transferring the initial data, 100 MB (5000x5000 matrix using float32) but then the execution of the second case should be slightly slower due to the random initialization at each run.

However, what I see is that the multiplication of the constant is much slower even on successive runs in the same session.

## The code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit
import os

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="2"  # nospam
SIZE = 5000
NUM_RUNS = 10

a = np.random.random((SIZE, SIZE))
_const_a = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float32, name="Const_A")
_mul_const_a = tf.matmul(_const_a, _const_a, name="Mul_Const")

_random_a = tf.random_uniform((SIZE, SIZE), dtype=tf.float32, name="Random_A")
_mul_random_a = tf.matmul(_random_a, _random_a, name="Mul_Random")

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as s:
    # Run once to make sure everything is initialised
    s.run((_const_a, _mul_const_a, _random_a, _mul_random_a))

    # timeit
    print("TF with const\t", timeit(lambda: s.run((_mul_const_a.op)), number=NUM_RUNS))
    print("TF with random\t", timeit(lambda: s.run((_mul_random_a.op)), number=NUM_RUNS))
```

## The output

```
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
Random_A/sub: (Sub): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A/RandomUniform: (RandomUniform): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A/mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A: (Add): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Mul_Random: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Mul_Const: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A/max: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A/min: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A/shape: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Const_A: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
TF with const    2.9953213009994215
TF with random   0.513827863998813
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call to session.run() in tensorflow is unreasonably expensive. If you want to benchmark something remember to call it repeatedly.

Though, in your case, unless you disable constant folding you're likely to see almost no time spent in the constant case as your graph will just fetch a constant.

Answer (score 0):

YMMV, I obtain opposite results on my modest K1100M.

```
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: Quadro K1100M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.0
Random_A/sub: (Sub): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A/RandomUniform: (RandomUniform): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A/mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A: (Add): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Mul_Random: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Mul_Const: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A/max: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A/min: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Random_A/shape: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Const_A: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
TF with const    4.3167382130868175
TF with random   9.889055849542306
```